# Automapper map dictionary<string,string> to object

Tags: c#, string, automapper

Can anyone help how to map dictionary to a class. With my below code, i am getting error at line `.ConvertUsing` saying "The call is ambiguous..."

```
CreateMap<Dictionary<string,string>, CustomClass>()
    .ConvertUsing(x =>
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<CustomClass>(serializer.Serialize(x));
    });
```

Thanks

Comment: I would never ever use AutoMapper for this. It adds a useless layer of indirection. Why don't you just deserialize right-away?

Comment: _Which_ call is ambiguous?  I agree with Gert, though - all AutoMapper is doing here is wrapping the deserialization - it's not mapping any properties_ which is what it's designed to do.

Comment: CustomClass, has few properties as DateTime. But the Dictionary has got string as datetime values. So i thought of using Automapper. Please let me know if you have the right implementation.

Comment: I agreet with Gert Arnold and didn't used Automapper for this. Thanks